# PICkit3 vs PICkit2

Tags: microcontroller, pic, tutorial, pickit

I would like to know the difference between the pickit3 and the pickit2?. Currently I'm studying in an electronics course and am using the pic18F. What I'm looking for is an introductory guide to programming the pics, and for the most part I hear that pickit2 is the most recommended. But having pickit3, which is better?, does it still have the same tutorial documentation and support and does it make pickit2 outdated?.

EDIT:
are the assembly startup lessons for the pickit2 outdated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PicKit3 is a little more advanced, and likely to be supported for longer. Some of the newer PICs may not be programmable/debuggable with the PICkit2. See MC website and look for devices supported by each, or check under MPLAB->Configure->Select Device and see if the circle next to the PICkit2 is red/yellow/green for a particular device.

For starting out learning with PICs, (in my opinion) the PICkit2 should be just fine, I have one and still use it from time to time (I have an ICD3 which is used generally) It also doubles as a basic logic analyser and serial port.

The lessons will still be relevant to pick up the basics. In short you a PICkit2 would probably last you quite some time before you needed to upgrade. I did as I needed a production programmer (see MC website for definitions/comparisons between their programmers/debuggers) that can be used with the PIC32 and latest offerings.

Comment: the picKit3 is so cheap I just bought it recently and I have been very happy. I did end up in a situation where a team of undergrads doing a project needed help getting the image on. I loaded up the pickkit3 and they just ran through and flashed the boards. Easy as pie. On larger images it also uses USB instead of a serial converter, so it would program what used to take 45 seconds in 2. Very nice feature if you are doing something such as tweaking a user interface.

Comment: If the cost is not a major issue (not checked lately) then it probably does make sense to get the PicKit3 (or even an ICD3) I heard they had a few teething problems but I think they have been ironed out now, and I'm sure they are quite a bit faster (I noticed a big difference too with the ICD3 compared to the PICkit2). I think either should be fine for starting out with though.

Comment: I just ordered the pickit3 not knowing that the example code was in C, whereas as I really wanted to learn the assembly side of things. Would the assembly lessons found on pickit2 work with pickit3?

Comment: Yes, for the assembly lessons it's the PIC that's more important, as different families may have different assembly instructions. If I recall correctly they were based on a 16F690, so this, or anything using the same instruction set should do (any 16Fxxx with ADC, comparator and PWM peripherals). Bear in mind you may need to adapt the lessons slightly for the demo board that (I assume) comes with the PICkit3. Or just set up on a breadboard. Either way, you should learn plenty, just dive in and if you get stuck, ask here :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Dave Jones](http://www.eevblog.com) did a great review for the **Pickit3** in comparison with the **Pickit2**.
You can find the video [here](http://www.eevblog.com/2009/10/21/eevblog-39-pickit-3-programmerdebugger-review/) .
If you're not used to working with pickit2, then pickit3 is a great tool. It also supports newer devices than pickit2.